# Inequality for primes

Tags: number-theory, inequality

Is the $n$'th prime number $P(n)$ always less than $n^2$ for $n>1$?
We see that $P(2) = 3 < 4$; $P(3) = 5 < 9$;..... is this true for all $n>1$?
Please provide a proof.

Comment: Use the prime number theorem and convenient error bounds.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm a high school student and have no knowledge of analytic number theory. Looking for an elementary proof.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, most of the useful bounds on the $n$-th prime function $P$ are rooted in analytic number theory. In particular, though, it’s known that for all $n > 5$:

$$P(n) <n \left( \log\left(n\right)+\log\left(\log n \right) \right)$$

An upper bound which is clearly less than $n^2$. The remaining cases $2 \leq n \leq 5$ are easy to check.